# Unable to load QMYSQL Driver on PySide2

Tags: python, mysql, pip, driver, pyside2

How can i install and load the Qmysql driver using Pyside2 (pip) with python3.8? I've already tried to download git:qtbase and compiled the driver from there but I had any luck.

Comment: I am using pyside2==5.15.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>This answer covers not only the installation for Linux but for the other OS, besides that it also applies for pyqt5</sub>

---

The binaries used by Qt are the same ones used by PyQt5/PySide2 since they use the same base code so you will have to compile the plugins.

In this case, to compile the mysql plugin you must follow [the official manual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql), which in summary is:

1. Install the dependencies, in this case the [mysql-connector-c](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/)
2. Install Qt of the same version with which pyqt5/pyside2 was compiled and development tools such as MSVC on windows, build-essentials on Ubuntu, XCode on MacOS, etc.
3. Download the source code, in this case the [qtbase repository](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/).
4. Compile the plugin.

To find out the version of Qt with the version that the library was compiled with, the following can be used:

- **PyQt5**

```
python -c "from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR; print('Qt version', QT_VERSION_STR)"
```

- **PySide2**

```
python -c "from PySide2.QtCore import qVersion; print('Qt version', qVersion())"
```

The above generates libqsqlmysql.so, qsqlmysql.dll or libqsqlmysql.dylib depending on the OS. That file must be pasted in the path:

- **PyQt5:**

```
python -c "import os; from PyQt5.QtCore import QLibraryInfo; print('QT_SQL_DRIVER_PATH', os.path.join(QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.PrefixPath), 'plugins', 'sqldrivers'))"
```

- **PySide2:**

```
python -c "import os; from PySide2.QtCore import QLibraryInfo; print('QT_SQL_DRIVER_PATH', os.path.join(QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.PrefixPath), 'plugins', 'sqldrivers'))"
```

---

To cover all the cases I have created a Github Actions that generates the binaries:

[**mysql_plugin.yml**](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/blob/master/.github/workflows/mysql_plugin.yml)

```yml
name: generate_mysql_plugin

on: [push]

jobs:
  ci:
    name: ${{ matrix.os.name }} Qt-${{ matrix.qt.qt_version }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os.runs-on }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os:
          - name: Windows
            extension: "dll"
            runs-on: windows-2019
          - name: Linux
            extension: "so"
            runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
          - name: MacOS
            extension: "dylib"
            runs-on: macos-10.15
        qt:
          - name: 5.15
            qt_version: 5.15.0
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Install Qt
        uses: jurplel/install-qt-action@v2
        with:
          version: ${{ matrix.qt.qt_version }}
          dir: ${{ github.workspace }}/qt/
      - name: clone qtbase
        run: git clone -b ${{ matrix.qt.qt_version }} https://code.qt.io/qt/qtbase.git
      - name: Compile mysql plugin on Windows
        if: matrix.os.name == 'Windows'
        shell: cmd
        run: |
          choco install wget
          wget https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/19/file/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64.zip
          unzip mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64.zip
          copy /y "mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64\lib\libmysql.dll" .
          call "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat"
          cd qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers
          qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="${{ github.workspace }}\mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64\include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="${{ github.workspace }}\mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64\lib"
          nmake sub-mysql
          nmake install
      - name: Compile mysql plugin on Linux
        if: matrix.os.name == 'Linux'
        run: |
          wget https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/19/file/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64.tar.gz
          tar zxvf mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64.tar.gz
          sudo cp mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/lib/*.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
          sudo apt-get install freetds-dev
          cd qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers
          qmake
          cd mysql
          qmake
          make
          make install
      - name: Compile mysql plugin on MacOS
        if: matrix.os.name == 'MacOs'
        run: |
          brew install wget
          wget https://cdn.mysql.com/archives/mysql-connector-c/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-macos10.12-x86_64.tar.gz
          tar zxvf mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-macos10.12-x86_64.tar.gz
          sudo cp mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-macos10.12-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-macos10.12-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient_r.dylib
          sudo cp mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-macos10.12-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-macos10.12-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient_r.18.dylib

          sudo cp mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-macos10.12-x86_64/lib/*.dylib /usr/local/lib
          cd qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers
          qmake -- MYSQL_PREFIX="${{ github.workspace }}/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-macos10.12-x86_64"
          make sub-mysql
          cd mysql
          make install
      - name: upload
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          path: qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/plugins/sqldrivers/*qsqlmysql.${{ matrix.os.extension }}
          name: mysqlplugin-${{ matrix.os.name }}-Qt${{ matrix.qt.name }}
```

The previous code generates the plugin that you can find [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/actions/runs/271657543).

---

In the specific case of Ubuntu it can be reduced to:

- Copy the [libqsqlmysql.so](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/suites/1242824503/artifacts/18829394) file to QT_SQL_DRIVER_PATH.
- Execute `sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev`

---

In the specific case of Windows it can be reduced to:

- Copy the [qsqlmysql.dll](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/suites/1242824503/artifacts/18829394) file to QT_SQL_DRIVER_PATH.
- Download the [mysql-connector-c for windows](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/19/file/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-winx64.zip) and copy the libmysql.dll next to your script.

Comment: I get 404 Errors when trying to open the [qsqlmysql.dll](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/suites/1242824503/artifacts/18829394) file.

Comment: @angelogro then download from https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/actions/runs/412607469

Answer (score 0):

P.S. almost half of this info is officially published at https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/deployment-plugins.html

I use PySide6 on Windows 10 and `%QT_SQL_DRIVER_PATH%` does not work for me.
What works for PySide6 is the `%QT_PLUGIN_PATH%` environment variable.

Let's assume that you have built (or downloaded) a SQL driver for Qt platform into `C:\projects\my-project-1\qt-plugins\sqldrivers`, so that there is `qsqlmysql.dll` there.

**CASE #1:** you execute `QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")`, but you get the following error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QPSQL
```

It means that `qsqlmysql.dll` (a plugin for Qt platform) was not found.

**The fix** is to define the environment variable `%QT_PLUGIN_PATH%` and put `qsqlmysql.dll` into `%QT_PLUGIN_PATH%/sqldrivers/`. You can even do it in your Python script *before* invocation of `QSqlDatabase.addDatabase`:

```
os.environ['QT_PLUGIN_PATH'] = r'C:\projects\my-project-1\qt-plugins'
```

Note, `qsqlmysql.dll` must be a release version built using MSVC (64-bit since it is year 2022), not MinGW. Debug version fails by some reason in my experience.

If you don't want to define the `%QT_PLUGIN_PATH%` environment variable, **an alternative fix** is to copy `qsqlmysql.dll` into *one* of these directories: `<python-install-dir>/sqldrivers/` or `<python-install-dir>/lib/site-packages/PySide6/plugins/sqldrivers/`.

**Another alternative** is to use `QCoreApplication.addLibraryPath` like this:

```
    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    app.addLibraryPath(r'C:\projects\my-project-1\qt-plugins')
```

**And yet another alternative** is to create
`<python-install-dir>\qt.conf` or `<python-install-dir>\qt6.conf` with following content:

```
[Paths]
Prefix=C:/projects/my-project-1
Plugins=qt-plugins
```

or even so:

```
[Paths]
Plugins=C:/projects/my-project-1/qt-plugins
```

N.B. **qt6.conf** is ignored if `qt.conf` doesn't exist. If you use `qt6.conf`, you **must** create an empty `qt.conf` at least.

---

**CASE #2:** you execute `QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")`, but you get the following error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QMARIADB QMYSQL QSQLITE QODBC QPSQL
```

It means that `qsqlmysql.dll` was found, but **its dependencies were not**.
The `qsqlmysql.dll` additionally requires 3 DLLs: `libmysql.dll`, `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll`, `libssl-1_1-x64.dll`.
These DLLs must be located in `%PATH%` or in current directory.

N.B. if you place the DLLs near your python script, this won't work if current working directory is different from scripts's location. But you can modify `%PATH%` even in your Python script.
For example, if you copied said DLLs into `deps` sub-directory of your project:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'deps')
```

---

Another possible issues might be:

- architecture mismatch (some DLLs are 64-bit, while others are 32-bit).
- binary incompatibility - e.g. if "sqldrivers/qsqlmysql.dll" is built with MinGW or it's a debug version downloaded from https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/

---

Define the environment variable: `set QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` - this might help to troubleshoot such issues.